# Where do dynamic dispatch is needed in java application software?

Tags: java

Where in software application in java dynamic dispatch might be useful ??

```java
class Student {
    int maxRollNo = 200;
}
class SchoolStudent extends Student{
    int maxRollNo = 120;
}
class CollegeStudent extends SchoolStudent{
    int maxRollNo = 100;
}
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Super class can contain subclass object.   
       Student obj1 = new CollegeStudent();
       Student obj2 = new SchoolStudent();

       //In both calls maxRollNo of super class will be printed.
       System.out.println(obj1.maxRollNo);
       System.out.println(obj2.maxRollNo);
    }
}
```

Above code is understandable but where in actual software development this Dynamic dispatch method is useful?

Comment: There is no "dynamic dispatch" going on in your code. What are you asking exactly? What research have you done (using Google, for example) ?

Comment: When is dynamic dispatch useful in Java software development?  When is air useful to humans?  Exaggeration? Yes, but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

Method overriding is one of the ways in which Java supports Runtime Polymorphism. Dynamic method dispatch is the mechanism by which a call to an overridden method is resolved at run time, rather than compile time.

1. When an overridden method is called through a superclass reference,
   Java determines which version(superclass/subclasses) of that method
   is to be executed based upon the type of the object being referred
   to at the time the call occurs. Thus, this determination is made at
   run time.
2. At run-time, it depends on the type of the object being referred to
   (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which
   version of an overridden method will be executed
3. A superclass reference variable can refer to a subclass object. This
   is also known as upcasting. Java uses this fact to resolve calls to
   overridden methods at run time.

Therefore, if a superclass contains a method that is overridden by a subclass, then when different types of objects are referred to through a superclass reference variable, different versions of the method are executed. Here is an example that illustrates dynamic method dispatch:

```
class Student {
    int maxRollNo = 200;

    void m1() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Inside Student 's m1 method"); 
    } 
}
class SchoolStudent extends Student{
    int maxRollNo = 120;

    void m1() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Inside SchoolStudent 's m1 method"); 
    } 
}
class CollegeStudent extends SchoolStudent{
    int maxRollNo = 100;

    void m1() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Inside CollegeStudent 's m1 method"); 
    } 
}
```

```
Student obj1 = new CollegeStudent();
SchoolStudent obj2 = new CollegeStudent();
CollegeStudent obj3 = new CollegeStudent();
Student obj4 = new SchoolStudent();
```

```
obj1.m1();
o/p :- Inside CollegeStudent 's m1 method

obj2.m1();
o/p :- Inside CollegeStudent 's m1 method

obj3.m1();
o/p :- Inside CollegeStudent 's m1 method

obj4.m1();
o/p :- Inside SchoolStudent's m1 method
```

Now In Java, we can override methods only, not the variables(data members), so runtime polymorphism cannot be achieved by data members. For example :

```
obj1.maxRollNo 
o/p :- 200

obj2.maxRollNo 
o/p :- 120

obj3.maxRollNo 
o/p :- 100

obj4.maxRollNo 
o/p :- 200
```

Comment: Instead of doing upcasting why can't we create object for respective class where the method we want to invoke is present? can you explain why actually needed in real-time.What is advantage of resolving the methode invoking at runtime?

Comment: dynamic dispatch is very useful concept. suppose you have 1 method to calculate interest rate in every sub class of bank. now when want to calcilate interest rate, you can just use bank obj reference to call interest method and compiler will ecide that which bank interest rate method should run.